# Store Object Reference in GUI Element

Tags: java, swing, object, reference

Does the `JCheckBox` (or other GUI elements) have a method or field to store a reference to another object? That way, when the "Listener" for that checkbox fires it can immediately get the associated object and do something to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such thing but you can implemented in several ways, at least two:

First, you can subclass `JCheckBox` (`MyJCheckBox`) and add to it what you need:

```
class MyJCheckBox extends JCheckBox {
  private Object o;
  public Object getObject() { return o; }
  public void setObject(Object o) { this.o = o; }
  // add necessaries ctors
}

// somewhere else
MyJCheckBox j = new MyJCheckBox(...);
j.setObject(...);
j.addActionListener(new MyListener());

class MyListener implements ActionListener {
  actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    MyJCheckBox jcb = (MyJCheckBox)(e.getSource());
    Object o = jcb.getObject();
  }
}
```

Second, you can use your own `Action`s implementation to provide any mechanism you need:

```
class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
  public static final String MY_KEY = "MY_KEY";
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object o = this.getValue(MY_KEY);
  }
}

// somewhere else
JCheckBox j = new JCheckBox(...);
MyAction a = new MyAction(...);
a.putValue(MyAction.MY_KEY,some_object);
j.addAction(a);
```